# Styling table with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a simple table:

```
<table class="caspGrid">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="caspRow">
            <td class="caspColEntity">
                <input type="checkbox"/>
                <span>Favorites</span>
                <p>(<span>2</span>)</p>
            </td>
            <td class="caspColSummary">
                <p>FY13 SPM Mobility Strategy</p>
                <p>FY13 SPM Mobility Strategy</p>
                <p>FY13 SPM Mobility Strategy</p>
            </td>
            <td class="caspColTeam">
                <p>Tim Smith</p>
                <p>Tim Smith</p>
                <p>Tim Smith</p>
            </td>
        </tr>               
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'd like the table to span the entire page height but I want each `<tr>` to wrap around the content and the last `<tr>` to span the rest of the way, how can I do that?

[HERE IS A FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Dvr2b/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [last-of-type CSS3 pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3alast-of-type):

```
tr:last-of-type {  
    height: 100%;
}
```

this will target only the last tr.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5L7fb/

If you have multiple tables in one page, then you should use `descendant` or `child` selectors:

```
/* Descendant */
table tr:last-of-type {  
    height: 100%;
}

/* Child */
table > tr:last-of-type {  
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, elegant and simple.